# Having issues with Django URL mapping

Tags: python, django

I am trying Django for an upcoming project and going through a tutorial and running into issue with defining URL paths. Below is the project structure showing the urls.py at the project root. 
The ***urls.py*** in my ***timer*** package is pretty simple:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

However when I launch the application and navigate to localhost:8080/timer/ I am getting a 404. Any suggestions what I should be looking at?

[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change URLs in the settings of the whole project like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^timer/$', include('timer.urls')),
]
```

As for the timer, the URLs will be like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
]
```

Don't forget about `r's` in the url().

Comment: thanks for taking time. It turns out that I created the urls.py under a wrong folder. I misunderstood the instructions and created the **urls.py** in the same folder as **manage.py**. Once I add the new url pattern in the file **projectdb/projectgb/urls.py,** the issue is fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I created the urls.py under a wrong folder. I misunderstood the instructions and created the **urls.py** in the same folder as **manage.py**. Once I add the new url pattern in the file **projectdb/projectgb/urls.py,** the issue is fixed. Thanks.